# Inserting value by index does not work after splitting a string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to insert a new index after splitting a string but it produces no value. Can anyone help?

```
#splitting of string
str = "my name is anant raj rathore"

var = (str.split(" "))

print(var)

# Fetching value from the split string
print(var[1])

# inserting in list--------here is the problem the result is none .
print(var.insert(3, 'sir'))
```

I know I am doing some mistake but don't know the exact issue

Comment: `list.insert` always returns None. In general (for the stdlib at least), if a method mutates the original object, it will usually return None to help indicate this.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to fix here. First of all don't name your variables things like `list, tuple, str, int, float` etc. Second of all split, by default will split at   if you leave it blank.

And your main problem is that var.insert() won't return anything. It just modifies an iterable. So storing it in a variable won't do any good either. Just keep `var.insert()` plain and simple.

```
strEx = "my name is anant raj rathore"

var = strEx.split()
print(var)
# Fetching value from the split string
print(var[1])

# inserting in list--------here is the problem the result is none .
var.insert(3, 'sir')
```

Allow me to share an example.
Say we had a function which added a char to the end of a list.

```
example = ['a','b']
def add_to_end(li,cha):
    li.append(cha)
add_to_end(example,'c')
```

Here, it does not have a return statement. It modified `example` by using `append`.
If we print example like this.

```
example = ['a','b']
def add_to_end(li,cha):
    li.append(cha)
add_to_end(example,'c')
print(example)
```

we get the correct output, with no `None`.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But say we printed the function, even though it has not return.

```
example = ['a','b']
def add_to_end(li,cha):
    li.append(cha)
print(add_to_end(example,'c'))
```

we get `None`.
Another option we have it to store it in a variable, `example`.

```
example = ['a','b']
def add_to_end(li,cha):
    li.append(cha)
example = add_to_end(example,'c')
print(example)
```

we get `None` once again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution .Got the point

Comment: Great to here. Please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

`insert()` method inserts object obj into list at offset index. **does not return any value** but it inserts the given element at the given index.

```py
print(var.insert(3, 'sir')) #None
```

So do print after calling insert.

```py
var.insert(3, 'sir')
print(var) #['my', 'name', 'is', 'sir', 'anant', 'raj', 'rathore']
```